# Workarounds For Phpunit's Incorrect File Sorting?

Tags: phpunit

Anyone know of a workaround for Phpunit's illogical file sorting? I've got tests in a subfolder with names like "AddMin001.php", "...002.php", etc. and Phpunit insists on running 002, 003, 004, then 001.

My attempts to use Phpunit.xml always produce: "Uncaught exception 'PHPUnit_Framework_Exception' with message 'Could not load "[redacted]phpunit.xml".' in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Util/XML.php:212".

Creating AllTests.php classes seems like a lot of extra work and maintenance, but if necessary I'll go that route.

Comment: Could you please explain why you need the tests to run it certain order? Are you trying to keep a global state or is it something else? Also, what is your phpunit version and how does the phpunit.xml file look like that fails to load?

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit does not sort tests at all, they are run in whatever order your filesystem is returning them. Could be creation date, could be something else, depends on the filesystem (and OS) in use. In any case, you can not rely on this order, because factors outside your tests can change it.

There are however a few tricks, that you could use - for example [test dependencies](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies).